# Javascript member variable undefined error though correctly defined

Tags: typescript

I am trying to copy the properties of one member variable to another member variable.  Both are of the same type. When I call 'trackChanges' the browser shows an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Can someone tell why this.originalData isn't known at runtime?

```
export class myClass {

  data: IMyData;
  originalData: IMyData;

  trackChanges() {
    for (const attr in this.data) {
      if (this.originalData.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        this.originalData[attr] = this.data[attr];
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    this.data.field1 = '123';
    this.data.field2 = 12;
  }
```

Comment: You still have to give a value explicitly. This is not how TypeScript works and you mixed `javascript` and `typescript` tags.

Comment: Elsewhere in my code I assign values to the properties of 'data'.  Does address your point? (not sure I got it)  I updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code do you assign a value to the member variables. Defining the in Typescript just tells the compiler that the members will exist on the object it is up to you to assign a value, either by using an initializer when you declare it, in the constructor, a method, or externally by accessing setting the member:

```
export class myClass {

    data: IMyData = {}; // Initialize using an object literal when declaring
    originalData: IMyData = {}; // Initialize using an object literal when declaring
    constructor(data: IMyData = {}) {
        this.originalData = Object.assign({}, this.data) // Create a copy of the original and assign it to the field
        this.data = data; // Assign data to the field
    }
    trackChanges() {
        for (const attr in this.data) {
            if (this.originalData.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                this.originalData[attr] = this.data[attr];
            }
        }
    }
}

var myInstance = new myClass({ name: "Jon"});
myInstance.data = {}; // External assignment
```

Comment: Does the line 'this.originalData = Object.assign({}, this.data)' do the exact same as my 'trackChanges' function?  That would be a lot simpler.  I thought you couldn't make a copy of an object (you had to assign one property at a time)?

Comment: `Object.assign` is es2015, so it might not be available in every browser, you might want to look at some polyfill to create fill the gaps for older browsers. But yes, `Object.assign` creates a shallow copy of data. Your implementation only copies from `data` to `originalData` only if `originalData` already has the property, `Object.assign` just copies all the `data` to a new object ( `{}` in this case).

Comment: Just researched that function.  Would this be better for a deep copy (as I have nested objects in the object): ' let copyobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(firstobj));

Comment: Simpler yes, better for performance, you would have to measure, but probably not since you have to construct the string representation of the object. But if you don't do this often, it might just work well enough.